# why the javascript program doesn't run

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xhtml

this is my program in java script i don't appear any thing when i press search but the function button-pressed() is worked perfectly lonely but when i using the code with form to take the sentence from the text it doesn't work .but when i try to print the result in many places i notice that every thing is OK else in the first for loop until now i don't know the reason please any help there is the code :

```
        <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <!-- Fig. 11.5: SearchingStrings.html -->
    <!-- String searching with indexOf and lastIndexOf. -->
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
          <title>
             Searching Strings with indexOf and lastIndexOf
          </title>
          <script type = "text/javascript">
             <!--


             function buttonPressed() 
             {

               // var searchForm = document.getElementById( "searchForm" );
                var inputVal = document.getElementById( "inputVal" ).value;
                var arr = inputVal.split(" ");

                arr.sort();

    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; ++i) {
        var num = arr[i];
        counts[num] = (counts[num] ? counts[num] : 0) + 1 ;

                    document.writeln(arr[i]+"</br>");
    }

    document.writeln("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxafter forrrrrrrr");
    document.writeln("<table border=\"4\">");
    document.writeln("<caption><h3>Search's Results: <h3/></caption>");
    for (var i in counts) {
        document.writeln("<tr><td>"+i+" :</td><td>"+counts[i]+"</td></tr>");
    }
    document.writeln("</tbody></table>");

             } // end function buttonPressed
             // -->
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
    <form action = "">
             <h1>The string to search is:<br />
                 </h1>
             <p>Enter Sentence  You want  To Find The Occurrence Of Each Word In It :
             <input id = "inputVal" type = "text"    />
             <input name = "search" type = "button" value = "Search"
                    onclick = "buttonPressed()" /><br /></p>


          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that `counts` variable is undefined in your script. So declare it and then try.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FZnpQ/)